# System.ArgumentException, Value does not fall within the expected range in metro app

Tags: xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

I am getting this exception, I have no clue whatsoever why it throws this `ArgumentException`.

Does anybody have an idea what is that can cause this exception to occur in a metro app?

Is it due to any mistake in XAML design or is it something else?

Comment: You need to post some code or something specific about your project where you get this error.

Answer (score 1):

You might be setting `Selector.SelectedItem` in a `ComboBox`, `ListView`, etc. to a value that is not actually in the bound `ItemsControl.ItemsSource` collection.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this method](http://blog.galasoft.ch/archive/2012/09/10/adventures-in-windows-8-solving-activation-errors.aspx), if there are no obvious issues in your code/xaml